# How to add space between a word and underlining in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How can I add space between a word and its underlining in a UIButton name?

How should I manage button constraints for all devices (5S, 6S, 6S+) in Swift for iOS?

Comment: Can you explain your problem bit bit more clearly??

Answer (score 1):

To add space between words change Title text type in Stroryboard from Plain to Attributed and then tup three dots and change text parameters

[image: Button parameters]
[image]